# How do I initialize the list created from a class to be used in searching?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried using the `Search` class shown below in the search delegate.

```
class Search extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  @override
  ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    return theme.copyWith(
      primaryColor: theme.primaryColor,
    );
  }

  late List<Note> notes;

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            query = "";
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.clear))
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        icon: AnimatedIcon(
          icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
          progress: transitionAnimation,
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement buildResults
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final suggestionlist = query.isEmpty
        ? notes
        : notes
            .where((element) => element.toLowerCase().startsWith(query))
            .toList();
    return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      itemCount: suggestionlist.length,
      staggeredTileBuilder: (index) => StaggeredTile.fit(2),
      crossAxisCount: 4,
      mainAxisSpacing: 4,
      crossAxisSpacing: 4,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final note = notes[index];
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () async {
            await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => NoteDetailPage(noteId: note.id!),
            ));
            this.notes = await Notes.instance.readAll();
          },
          child: NoteCard(note: note, index: index),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

There is a list `late List<Note> notes;` which I created from a class `Note` in the above code which was to be used to create a staggered grid view. The class `Note` is in another dart file and is shown below:

```
class Note{
  final int? id;
  final String title;
  final String content;
  final bool favourite;
  final int number;
  final DateTime created;

  const Note({this.id,required this.title,required this.content,required this.favourite,required this.number,required this.created});
```

The staggered grid view works well in the homescreen and the code is as shown below :

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      itemCount: notes.length,
                      staggeredTileBuilder: (index) => StaggeredTile.fit(2),
                      crossAxisCount: 4,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 4,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 4,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final note = notes[index];

                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () async {
                            await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  NoteDetailPage(noteId: note.id!),
                            ));
                            refreshNotes();
                          },
                          child: NoteCard(note: note, index: index),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
```

but the problem comes in the searching. I want it to display all the items in the list `late List<Note> notes;` before a character is entered in the search text field then appropriate results after a character is entered in the search bar.

but I got the following error:

```
The following LateError was thrown building _SearchPage<String>(dirty, dependencies:
[_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#b7f3d], _InheritedTheme], state: _SearchPageState<String>#aae09):      
LateInitializationError: Field 'notes' has not been initialized.
```

How do I go about that?

Comment: Try replacing `late List<Note> notes;` with `List<Note> notes = [];` or some other default value.

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work. I got the following error :                                                     The following RangeError was thrown building:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0